# Analytics Reports Google Sheets with apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-analytics

I am using this code to generate Analytics reports on a Google spreadsheet.

The problem is that it overwrites data every time on execution.

What should I change, so that data gets append? So that the same spreadsheet is updated every day?

```
  const report = Analytics.Data.Ga.get(tableId, startDate, endDate, metric,
      options);

  if (report.rows) {
  var prop = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var spreadsheetId = prop.getProperty("spreadsheetId");
  var spreadsheet;
  
  if (spreadsheetId) {
    spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
  } else {
    spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create('Google Analytics Report');
    prop.setProperty("spreadsheetId", spreadsheet.getId());
  }
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.clear();  // Clear sheet.

  // Append the headers.
  const headers = report.columnHeaders.map((columnHeader) => {
    return columnHeader.name;
  });
  sheet.appendRow(headers);

  // Append the results.
  sheet.getRange(2, 1, report.rows.length, headers.length).setValues(report.rows);

  Logger.log('Report spreadsheet created: %s', spreadsheet.getUrl());
} else {
  Logger.log('No rows returned.');
}
}
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace the first parameter (that is 2) in getRange method with report.getLastRow() to obtain the first row empty to append the new data.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [appendRows_()](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/159426/269219) utility function. You can replace the lines starting at `sheet.clear()` with this:

`appendRows_(sheet, report.rows);`